# Create view that sums, select min and select max of child table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, that I would like to join to a view

Commission table:

```
idCommission: int
name:         varchar
...
```

Season:

```
idSeason:     int
since:        date
till:         date
```

Seasons_in_commission:

```
idCommission: int
idSeason:     int
```

Result view:

```
idCommission: int    | ID for referencing
Commission.*         | All other from Commission table
since:        date   | Min of all its (from) seasons
till:         date   | Max of all its (till) seasons
seasons:      int    | Count of its seasons
```

I have tried, but I found, that I need to reference row by row in the sub-queries, that I don't know how to do.

```
SELECT Commission.*, 
MIN(
  SELECT since FROM Seasons_in_commission 
  JOIN Season USING(idSeason) 
  WHERE idCommission = currentRow.idCommission /*<- this part is wrong */
) as Since, MAX(...) as Till, COUNT(...) as Seasons FROM Commission
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need any subqueries. Try this:

```
SELECT Commission.*, MIN(since) AS Since, MAX(till) AS Till, COUNT(*) AS Seasons
  FROM Commission
  JOIN Seasons_in_commission USING (idCommission)
  JOIN Season USING (idSeason)
 GROUP BY idCommission;
```

(Note that this will only work with [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) disabled.)

Comment: The count does work, but the dates taken from its first season only. No min or max done

Comment: @Akxe I can't help further without some actual data. If you could set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) database that would be a big help.

Comment: And you were right, I did mistype max as min... Thank you very much